# Which free on line dictionaries is considered the best for English-Russian (and vise versa) translations?

Tags: словарь

Which **on line dictionaries** is considered the best and accurate for **English-Russian** (and vise versa) translations?

Google translate makes a lot of mistakes.

Comment: Yandex is great from Russian to English.

Comment: ^Thank you. https://translate.yandex.com/?lang=en-ru&text=AFTERNOON

Comment: Consider http://www.lingvo.ru as well.

Answer (score 3):

For terminology, I prefer (in order of descending reliability) [ru.wikipedia.org](http://ru.wikipedia.org/), [wiktionary.org and](https://ru.wiktionary.org/), last but not least, [multitran.ru](http://multitran.ru/) (I generally mistrust 'hive-mind platforms', though-- especially those in Russian language).

For corpus samples, I normally accept [linguee.ru](http://linguee.ru/)

Google.translate is often [funny](https://tjournal.ru/43919-google-translate-goes-crazy) (but it can be improved).

Comment: Thank you!1^ Btw, I found many mistake in Google translate for En-Ru then personally I highly recommend to avoid it as possible.

Comment: Reverso is much better than Linguee in my opinion.

Comment: Google translate is really quick, which is OK if you just want a vague idea of what the text might be about and don't really care about accuracy, but even as a native English speaker with poor/weak command of Russian I can often notice mistakes in Google's translations in both directions (for example, Google does not seem to understand at all that the Dative case is used for indirect objects and not direct objects).

Answer (score 3):

Well, I never use one dictionary. Lingvo-online.ru or lingvo.ua., wooordhunt.ru., dict.academic.ru.,multitran.ru.